# Creating a DSA Signature from the Linux command line

Tags: unix, cryptography, dsa

I'm looking for a Linux/Unix command-line tool to create a DSA signature from a given file/data and a private key.

I know about the [xmlsec1 tool](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/). But I would like something simpler. It seems that OpenSSL provides this function as a developer library, but not as a tool.

Answer (score 3):

It's done with "openssl dgst" - not the most obvious place to put it...

Found in:

http://www.myelin.co.nz/post/2005/5/23/

```
openssl dsaparam 1024 < /dev/random > dsaparam.pem

openssl gendsa dsaparam.pem -out dsa_priv.pem

openssl dsa -in dsa_priv.pem -pubout -out dsa_pub.pem

echo "foobar" > foo.txt

sha1sum < foo.txt | awk '{print $1}' > foo.sha1

openssl dgst -dss1 -sign dsa_priv.pem foo.sha1 > sigfile.bin

openssl dgst -dss1 -verify dsa_pub.pem -signature sigfile.bin foo.sha1
```

Comment: Late but: `dgst -sign/verify` hashes _and_ PK-signs/verifies (including DSA), so your sequence actually double-hashes, which is equally secure but not standard/interoperable. Effective with OpenSSL 1.0.0 (released 2010) you no longer need the `-dss1` hack, you can use `-sha1` with a DSA key -- and `-sha224` and `-sha256` for the larger DSA sizes specified by FIPS 186-3 and later (which officially became mandatory for USgovt as of 2014).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for your note! I've made a tentative modern and correct alternative [there](https://serverfault.com/a/934007/183704), but it needs to be vetted.

Answer (score 1):

The following *tentative* set of commands seems to work with openssl 1.0.2g and 1.1.0g. Compared to that [other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/220508/183704), it aims to generate a signature of the file (including the standard-mandated hash step), rather than a signature (including a second hash step) of the lowercase hexadecimal ASCII representation of a first hash of the file. Also it uses more modern hash and modulus size.

```
# generate parameters with 2048-bit DSA, SHA-256 (can be common to multiple keys)
openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm DSA -pkeyopt dsa_paramgen_bits:2048 -pkeyopt dsa_paramgen_q_bits:256 -pkeyopt dsa_paramgen_md:sha256 -out dsaparams.pem

# generate a private key and extract the public key
openssl genpkey -paramfile dsaparams.pem -out dsaprivkey.pem
openssl dsa -in dsaprivkey.pem -pubout > dsapubkey.pem

# create a file "myfile" to be signed
echo 'The Magic Words are Squeamish Ossifrage' > myfile

# create signature "myfile.sig"
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign dsaprivkey.pem myfile > myfile.sig

# verify "myfile" against signature "myfile.sig" and public key
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify dsapubkey.pem -signature myfile.sig myfile
```

---

Note: A [former attempt](https://serverfault.com/revisions/934007/1) made openssl 1.0.2g generate signatures with 160-bit *q* (perhaps using SHA-1). Per [comment](https://serverfault.com/posts/comments/1211975?noredirect=1), I added `-sha256` to `openssl dgst`, but it made no difference. Experiments suggest it is necessary to use `-pkeyopt dsa_paramgen_q_bits:256`, even though the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/genpkey.html) explicitly states `-pkeyopt dsa_paramgen_md:sha256` takes care of that:

> `dsa_paramgen_md:digest`
>   The digest to use during parameter generation. Must be one of `sha1`, `sha224` or `sha256`. If set, then the number of bits in *q* will match the output size of the specified digest and the `dsa_paramgen_q_bits` parameter will be ignored (..)

Comment: Since you didn't specify the hash, in 1.0.2 (and down to 1.0.0) `dgst` defaults to MD5 -- and no standard ever defined/allowed DSA with MD5, so this probably won't interop (though OpenSSL-to-OpenSSL works). 1.1.0 (and now 1.1.1) defaults to SHA256 and DSA+SHA256 (for p-size 2k or 3k) is standard since 186-3 in 2008 -- although some implementations lagged; Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK Java didn't support this until j8 in 2014, and today in 2018 SO still gets Qs from people stuck on 7 or even 6 or 5. Personally I'd specify it for clarity even when the default is good.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for having checked! Indeed my former script did not work as intended: the signature generated by openssl 1.0.2g had two components of 160 bits (or slightly less), which suggests the use of SHA-1 (or a smaller hash such as MD5). I added `-sha256` to `openssl dgst` but if it made no difference in the signature format. I hope I nailed down the issue to `dsa_paramgen_md:sha256` not forcing `dsa_paramgen_q_bits:256` despite what the man page states. I have left `-sha256` in `openssl dgst` but I'm unsure of what that does.

Comment: r,s in DSA signature are mod q, and thus the same size or slightly smaller, NOT the size of the hash used if that is different; see 186-3 (or 4) 4.6, 4.7 and 4.2 which _recommends_ in effect hash size = q size (called N) but explicitly does not require it. OpenSSL 1.1.0 up `EVP_PKEY_{sign,verify}*` used by `pkeyutl -sign/verify` does check that the provided data size matches the _specified_ hash (even though it doesn't actually perform that hash)

Comment: Yes, dsa_paramgen_md does not set q size; the genpkey man page is clearly wrong. (It _almost_ describes the behavior of the old DSA_generate* API used by `gendsa` NOT the EVP_PKEY[_CTX] one used by `genpkey`.) In fact checking the source it doesn't even work in 1.0.0 1.0.1 1.0.2 below k and 1.1.0 below d. But since OpenSSL doesn't store the seed,count values that could be used for parameter validation, it doesn't actually matter what the paramgen hash is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:

- [`openssl gendsa`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/gendsa.html#)
- [`openssl dsa`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dsa.html#)
- [`openssl pkcs8`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html#)

Comment: Yes, these manage the keys, but don't encrypt/decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a signature for a file such that the integrity of that file can be verified? I think you're looking for Gnu Privacy Guard (GnuPG).

```
gpg --output filename.sig --detach-sig filename
```

This creates a signature file, filename.sig, based on the original, filename, that can be verified with

```
gpg --verify filename.sig filename
```

Comment: Was looking for something simpler, just using the DSA private key without GPG infrastructure, but let me see if this will do.